# Convert tuple of dictionary to list

Tags: python

how to convert this

```
({'content': 'home'}, {'content': 'home2'})
```

to

```
['home','home2']
```

sorry i am a beginner in python programming.
hope someone can help me thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension. This assumes your tuple is stored in the variable `tuple_list`.

```py
arr = [i['content'] for i in tuple_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every element is a dictionary with a single key that is always `'content'`:

```
t = ({'content': 'home'}, {'content': 'home2'})
values_list = [d['content"] for d in t]
```

Read up on python iterators, list comprehensions and tuple and dict datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

The @Bianconi answer is the correct way. But another way for you(beginner) can be:

```
new_list=[] #new variable list
tuple_list=({'content': 'home'}, {'content': 'home2'}) #your data

# a for loop that read the data from tuple_list and put it into new_list. 
for item in tuple_list:
    new_list.append(item['content'])
print new_list
```

Hope this helps.